# Used 3 element linear data for training a model and I included an outlier test data. Why is the test accuracy still at 100%?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have an input that is an array of 3 elements and I am using binary classification.

[image: Linear Data]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="2"



X_train = [
    [0,1,2],
    [0,2,4],
    [0,6,12],

    [0,7,14],
    [0,8,16],
    [0,11,22]
    ]

X_train = np.array(X_train)

y_train = [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    1
]
y_train = np.array(y_train)


X_test= [
    [0,3,6],
    [0,5,10],
    [0,10,20],
    [0,9,18],
    [0,0,100], # << outlier data
    ]
X_test = np.array(X_test)


y_test = [
    0,0,1,1,1
]
y_test = np.array(y_test)



model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(3,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.05), 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, verbose=1)
eval_result = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("Test loss:", eval_result[0], "Test accuracy:", eval_result[1])
```

I added a line *[0,0,100], # << outlier data*  which is a test data that is not linear. I classified it as 1. When I run the model.evaluate, the test accuracy is 100% and I expect that this should be less than 100% (80% accuracy due to 20% error = 1 error out of 5 test data) as I assume that there is a linear separation on [0,6.5,13].

I tried changing the outlier data to *[0,-50,100], # << outlier data* and I got a test accuracy of 80% which is what I expected to happen as well on the [0,0,100]. I believe I am missing something fundamental here but can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Universal Function Approximation theorem, a standard Neural Network ( NN ) with a definite number of hidden units **can approximate any function**. See [here](https://medium.com/predict/artificial-neural-networks-universal-function-approximators-cf5198224b58).

Say you have a function f( x, y ). The NN will approximate this function given the inputs and outputs of this function.

> Hence, a NN tries to establish a relationship between its inputs and
>   outputs and not among its features.

In your case, the NN didn't learn the relationship between the features i.e (0, x, 2x ). Instead, it learned to categorize a set of values ( x1, x2, x3 ) into class 1 or class 0.

Comment: thanks a lot Shubham. I had been trying to figure out how to do that. 

any hints on the things that I could add/modify on my model?

I had been reading more about CNNs and one of the example I saw is something like:

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’, input_shape=(28,28,1)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(10, activation=’softmax’))

I am planning to implement using this but I am interested to know if i am heading the right direction.

Comment: by the way, thanks for sharing the article you wrote. :) After I saw the RELU graph below, I remember seeing some articles on the web saying that the nowadays, RELU or non leaky RELU should be used nowadays and avoid using sigmoid (which I apparently used on the code above) and tanh.